# why datepicker show on top left in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am using material UI + react hook form .
https://react-hook-form.com/get-started

https://mui.com/material-ui/

I am trying to make datepicker. but I am facing one issue . My date picker open on **top left** why ?

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-currying-iuptqe?file=/src/App.tsx

```
<Controller
        control={control}
        name="date"
        rules={{
          validate: {
            min: (date) => isFuture(date) || "Please, enter a future date"
          }
        }}
        render={({ field: { ref, onBlur, name, ...field }, fieldState }) => (
          <DatePicker
            {...field}
            inputRef={ref}
            label="Date"
            renderInput={(inputProps) => (
              <TextField
                {...inputProps}
                onBlur={onBlur}
                name={name}
                error={!!fieldState.error}
                helperText={fieldState.error?.message}
              />
            )}
          />
        )}
      />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experiments, it seems that it could be because the posted sandbox is having the latest version of MUI, but pairing with an outdated version of [`@mui/x-date-pickers`](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/).

Updated `@mui/x-date-pickers` to the latest 5.0.13 to match the main MUI version and it looks to be fixed.

Forked demo with the update: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-date-picker-pn4nye?file=/src/App.tsx:356-376)